# Add firebase_ml_vision to flutter raise an error 'Unknown type name 'FIRVisionCloudLabelDetector'

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-mlkit

When add firebase_ml_vision: 0.3.0 to an existing project, when building xcode always complain about: Unknown type name 'FIRVisionCloudLabelDetector'.

The project can be compiled if firebase_ml_vision excluded.

Here is my flutter doctor result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.1.9, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

I tried to reinstall cocoapods and upgrade both flutter using 'flutter upgrade' and pods using 'cd ios && pod update', still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, a workaround would be to downgrade the `MLVisionLabelModel`.

To do so open your project in xcode and open the `Podfile` then add

```
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionLabelModel', '5.15.0'
```

and rerun. it should work fine.

Comment: I just had this issue, and today I was able to get the build working on iOS by upgrading all three of these to 5.16.0.

Answer (score 0):

My pod file had the following areas changed and I was getting this same issue:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

...

target 'Runner' do

  use_frameworks!

...

  pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVisionBarcodeModel', '5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVisionLabelModel', '5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel', '5.15.0'
```

I changed all the 5.15.0 to 5.16.0, and did the command: 'pod update' and this issue went away.  I also was playing games before a bit betweeen ios and androidX builds with pubspec.yaml.  I had the following for androidX builds:

```
  # Build for AndroidX
  #firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.2
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.8.0

  # Build for iOS
  #firebase_ml_vision: ^0.2.1

  flutter_camera_ml_vision: ^2.2.1
```

and it worked.  But then gave upgrade issues for iOS.  So now once I went to 5.16.0 I'm able to JUST have the following line ONLY:

```
  flutter_camera_ml_vision: ^2.2.1
```